# Converting character M/D/Y fields to date where one or more may be missing

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a date variable with the CATS function (Combining day, month, and year variables).
I keep getting LOG errors when the either month, day, or year variable is missing.

The LOG looks like this...

```
NOTE: Invalid argument to function INPUT at line 41 column 12.
USUBJID=XYZ-01-002 event_seq=2 estd=31 estm=JAN esty=2013 eend=. eenm=FEB eeny=2013
EVSTDT=31-JAN-2013 EVENDT=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=3
```

Here is my code...

```
filename event URL "http://www.stat.wmich.edu/wang/680/data/event.csv";
RUN;
Data events;
Infile event  delimiter=',' dsd firstobs=1;
    Informat
        USUBJID $10. event_seq 2. estd $UPCASE2.
        estm $UPCASE3. esty $UPCASE4. eend $UPCASE2.
        eenm $UPCASE3. eeny $UPCASE4.;
    Input USUBJID event_seq estd estm esty eend eenm eeny;
If estd = "UN" then estd = '.';  If eend = "UN" then eend = '.';
If eeny = "UNK" then eeny = '.'; If esty = "UNK" then esty = '.';
If esty = " " then esty = '.';   If eeny = " " then eeny = '.';
If eend = " " then eend = '.';   If estd = " " then estd = '.';
If estm = " " then estm = '.';   If eenm = " " then eenm = '.';
    Label 
    USUBJID = "Subject ID"         event_seq = "Event Sequence"
    esty = "Estimated Start Year"  estd = "Estimated Start Day"
    estm = "Estimated Start Month" eend = "Estimated End Day"
    eenm = "Estimated End Month"   eeny = "Estimated End Year";
RUN;
PROC SORT Data = events Out=ev_raw;
BY USUBJID event_seq;
RUN;
DATA event_log;
    Set ev_raw;
        EVSTDT = input(cat(estd, estm, esty), date9.);
        EVENDT = input(cat(eend, eenm, eeny), date9.);
    Format
        EVSTDT EVENDT date11.;
RUN;
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you expect to get when you input a date that is missing month, day, or year?  If I tell you a date is "January 2001", and you're forced to point to a specific square on the calendar, which square are you pointing to?

You need to have some code to deal with this.  Sometimes you might choose default of day=1 when day is left out, and default month=1 when month is left out (and force day=1 also, as it's less specific).  If year is left out I have no idea what you'd do other than set the whole date to missing, unless year is not very important in your particular use case.  Others might default the day to 15 or the month to 6 or 7 (as that's the mean of the possible values).  Others simply set the date to missing if any component is missing.

What you choose to do is dependent on your data and your needs, but you have to give SAS something to work with; it won't make decisions for you.

Comment: What I'd like to do is a assign a missing value of " " (blank), or at the very least "." or "NA". I know SAS might take issue with this, but am I forced to use character formatting? for example... EVSTDT = input(catx("/", estd, estm, esty), char11.);

Comment: You're welcome to store it as a character variable, but you are not currently doing this: you are inputting it to a date-formatted numeric, which cannot have this concept of missing component values.  If you want to store it as character, just use `CATS` or `CATX` and don't use `input` (ie, `EVSTDT=catx('/',estd,estm,esty);` and earlier define the length of `EVSTDT` to be 11).

Comment: at Joe... My programming knowledge is mostly limited to SAS, R, and LaTeX. Is there anywhere you might direct me so that I know how to appropriately post questions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your question, though you include more code than is necessary - easier if you present a short example with only the limited bit you're interested in, though in this case it's not that excessive.